# How to solve $y'-\frac{y}{x}=x^2e^x$, $y(1)=2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the step by step solution for this differential equation $y'-\frac{y}{x}=x^2e^x$, $y(1)=2$?

Comment: Please do some effort. This is a linear differential equation...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For a differential equation of the form $y'+f(x)y = g(x)$, define $\mu(x) = \exp\left(\int f(x)\, dx\right)$. Then
$$y(x) = \frac{1}{\mu(x)}\int \mu(x)g(x)\, dx$$

Answer (score 2):

We begin by eliminating exponential by putting 
$$y=ze^x $$
it becomes

$$z'+z-z/x=x^2$$

without right side, we have

$$z'/z=1/x-1$$

$$\ln (z/k)=\ln (|x|)-x $$

$$z=k xe^{-x}$$

for particular solution
$$z_p=k (x)xe^{-x}$$ with
$$k'(x)=xe^{x} $$
$$k (x)=(x-1)e^{x} $$
$$z=kxe^{-x}+x(x-1)$$
$$y=kx+x(x-1)e^x $$
with initial condition

> $$y=2x+x (x-1)e^x$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$y'-\frac { y }{ x } =x^{ 2 }e^{ x }\\ \frac { { y }^{ \prime  }x-y }{ x } ={ x }^{ 2 }{ e }^{ x }\\ \frac { { y }^{ \prime  }x-y }{ { x }^{ 2 } } =x{ e }^{ x }\\ { \left( \frac { y }{ x }  \right)  }^{ \prime  }={ x }{ e }^{ x }\\ \frac { y }{ x } =\int { x{ e }^{ x }dx } =\int { xd\left( { e }^{ x } \right)  } =x{ e }^{ x }-{ e }^{ x }+C\\ y\left( x \right) =x\left( x{ e }^{ x }-{ e }^{ x }+C \right) \\ $$ and since $y\left( 1 \right) =2$ we have $$y\left( 1 \right) =\left( e-e+C \right) =2\quad  \Rightarrow C=2\\ $$
$$\color{red}{\\ y\left( x \right) =x\left( x{ e }^{ x }-{ e }^{ x }+2 \right) \\ }$$

Comment: Nice when two different ways give the same answer.